# Why is throw and catch hardly ever used in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, catch-block

I have recently gotten into a discussion over `raise` vs. `throw`. There is [another SO thread discussing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018137/where-are-catch-and-throw-useful-in-ruby), and the pundits summarized the situation as this:

- Throw and raise are, to a great degree, interchangeable
- Advantage of `throw` is that you can throw easily anything, and that you don't waste time putting together the stack trace

That leaves me with a question, why nobody is actually using throw in Ruby? The thread discussed earlier mentioned use of catch / throw in Sinatra to handle HTTP error codes, but still, I have seen very few catch / throw examples in the wild, and I only used it in my own code once. As current Rails security crisis has shown, Ruby community widely ignores important features ($SAFE level in this particular case). So what is the thing with catch / throw?